# Angularjs brackets syntax

Tags: angularjs

I was reading https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop which has this example:

```
function foo(callback) {
  var result = calculateResult();
  (callback || angular.noop)(result);
}
```

I can't work out what this line is doing:

```
  (callback || angular.noop)(result);
```

It looks like `callback` and `angular.noop` are functions that can return `true` or `false`, but what is the value used for, and what does `(result)` do next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left side determines which function reference to use and the right side invokes that function passing in `result` as parameter

In more verbose form it is the same as doing:

```
if (callback) {
  callback(result)
} else {
  angular.noop(result)
}
```

Comment: So it calls callback, which returns true or false, and then if it's true, it once again calls callback passing in result as the argument?

Comment: More like using the outer function with or without passing in a callback. `foo()` vs `foo(function(result){ /* do something*/})`

Comment: I understand now. The callback in the if statement is not being called (because it doesn't have () after it), it's just being tested for null/undefined. If it's not null/undefined then it will be called with result as the argument.